# Undefined in golang struct

Tags: go

I have this struct

```
type Claim struct {
    Email `json:"email"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}
```

but when I do a BUILD I have this error

```
models/models.go:29:2: undefined: Email
```

What's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You're missing the type of the `Email` field. If you specify only the name of the field, without a type, the compiler assumes you're trying to *embed* a type called `Email` into the struct, that is why you get the `undefined` error. If you would have declared a type called `Email` in the same package you would be able to do the embedding just like you're doing with `jwt.StandardClaims`, although that is probably not what you're trying to do, so just make sure to include the type. More on struct fields and embedding can be found here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types

Answer (score 2):

When writing a struct, you have to specify a type :

```
type Claim struct {
    Email string `json:"email"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. You're right